# How do I write a scope for some object from a many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, many-to-many

I need to write a scope that I will pass a user's id through and will collect all the user's list associates with all the companies for that user from the `users` table.

In User.rb:

```
has_many :employments
has_many :companies, :through => :employments, :dependent => :destroy
...
```

In Employment.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

In Company.rb:

```
has_many :employments
has_many :users, :through => :employments, :dependent => :destroy
```

This could be possible using something like:

```
current_user.companies.each{|c| c.users.each {|u| u}}
```

but writing like this I think is much more time consuming.

Comment: what happens if you execute User.last!.companies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (not tested) scope finds all companies where a given user had work.

```
class Company
  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, :through => :employments, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :with_user, lambda { |user_id| joins(:employments).where(:user => user_id) }
  ...
```

Run `rails c` and execute try `Company.with_user(User.last!.id)` and see what happens.